# Add a value in Pandas at the end of rows with same ID

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame like below:

```
           ID   value  line_end
     1     1    5      -1
     2     1    5      -1
     3     1    7      -1
     4     2    3      -1
     5     2    4      -1
     6     2    8      -1
     7     2    23     -1
     8     3    12     -1
     9     4    1      -1
     10    4    2      -1
     11    4    3      -1
     12    4    5      -1
     13    5    2      -1
```

What I want to do is to add the value -2 at the end of the last row from a set of rows with the same ID. It should look like below. Should I use a for loop or there is other way?

```
           ID   value  line_end
     1     1    5      -1
     2     1    5      -1
     3     1    7      -1 -2
     4     2    3      -1
     5     2    4      -1
     6     2    8      -1
     7     2    23     -1 -2
     8     3    12     -1 -2
     9     4    1      -1
     10    4    2      -1
     11    4    3      -1
     12    4    5      -1 -2
     13    5    2      -1 -2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach can be this:

```
df['line_end'] = np.where(df['ID']!= df['ID'].shift(-1), df['line_end'].map(str)+' -2',df['line_end'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` provided "line_end" is a string column.

```
df.line_end = df.line_end.astype(str)
idx = df.groupby('ID').line_end.apply(lambda x: x.index[-1])
df.loc[idx, 'line_end'] += ' -2'

print(df) 
    ID  value line_end
1    1      5       -1
2    1      5       -1
3    1      7    -1 -2
4    2      3       -1
5    2      4       -1
6    2      8       -1
7    2     23    -1 -2
8    3     12    -1 -2
9    4      1       -1
10   4      2       -1
11   4      3       -1
12   4      5    -1 -2
13   5      2    -1 -2
```

Comment: @dmtrshpv You can only accept one answer.... so when you accepted the other answer, this was unaccepted. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: I wanted to accept both, because both work in my case

Comment: @dmtrshpv please accept the solution you ended up using. Thanks.